# SOCKS Proxy, Why do most browsers support them?

Tags: proxy, browser, socks

I've noticed that pretty much all the popular browsers support SOCKS Proxy, but have failed to understand as to why would that be the case.

What make's SOCKS Proxy important enough to be supported by the browsers?

Answer (score 1):

SOCKS, specially SOCKS5, has some valuable features that make it unique:

- It's very lightweight. So lightweight that in most cases the client only has to **start** the connection by doing the handshake, and later packets in the same connections work normally as if there is no proxy.
- Is a very low-level proxy, so it can be easily implemented at the network-level code of every software and library, without any affect on the higher-level code.
- Supports a good number of authentication methods.
- Supports DNS lookup through proxy.
- Supports IPv6.
- Is very easy to set up. As easy as `ssh -D`.
- Is standardized by RFC documents.

But honestly, I'm not sure if any of the above are the main reasons for it's popularity. An important reason is that there are not really much other proxies available. And don't forget that in the world network protocols change is not always welcome, even if there are better options than the established ones. Think HTTP and email.

Answer (score 0):

SOCKS is a very simple protocol to implement and has small overhead, compared to an HTTP proxy for instance.